# Servlet: Not able to get the response back to ajax function(in success block)

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

From jsp i need upload file through ajax call that intern make a request to servlet and upon completion of upload process i need control back to ajax functon so that i can show all imported data to the user.

//  Here is my code of

```
    <form id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="TestUpload"
     onsubmit="validate();" >
    Name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br>
    File : <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></input><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ></input>  
    </form>



// ajax function :

 var validate = function() {

    var form = $('#form1');
    strContent = $.getMultipartData('#'+this.id);
    var programId = $('#name').val();
    if (programId == "") {
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax( {
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        enctype:form.attr('enctype'),
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+strContent[0],
        data: form.serialize,
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#status').val(data);
        }
    });
   };
```

and Servlet code to process the form data using mutlipartRequest.

```
public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws       
    ServletException,IOException{
    System.out.println("Got Request");
    File file = null;
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String filePath = "c:\\test";
    MultipartRequest processFile  = new MultipartRequest(request, filePath);
    file = processFile.getFile("file");
    String fileName = file.getName();
    System.out.println("Valule of text field Name is :\t" +      
    processFile.getParameter("name"));
    System.out.println("FileName is :\t" + fileName);
    out.println("success");
    out.close();
}
```

//Once the process is done i want to respond back to ajax call am not able find the proper solution.

Comment: Do you see logs/sysouts in your servlet showing success? Also, try out.write instead of out.println and then do a flush - out.flush, do not close it.

Comment: I am getting sysouts in servlet for success/failure and also i tried out.write instead of out.println still I am not able to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

The json or xml(Internet data) sent back cannot be shown in alert, try putting it in console.log. even then if it doesn't work then convert the object returned to array and then use.